# SFML: no matching function to Thread()

Tags: c++, sfml

I try to use a SFML Thread in my game, but I got a problem with it.
My code:

```
void MyGame::endGame()
{
    sf::Thread thread(&PuzzleGame::endThread);
    thread.Launch();
}

void MyGame::endThread()
{

}
```

As a result I get:

```
../src/MyGame.cpp: In member function ‘void MyGame::endGame()’:
../src/MyGame.cpp:186:51: error: no matching function for call to ‘sf::Thread::Thread(void (MyGame::*)())’
sf::Thread thread(&MyGame::endThread);
                                    ^
```

What can be a problem?

**EDIT**
I use SFML 1.6

Answer (score 1):

```
thread.launch();
```

Note the lowercase.

Here's the docs in case you're interested:

http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/system-thread.php

Comment: Forgot to mention: I use SFML 1.6.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a class-function, you need to pass the object that you want to call it on, too:

```
void MyGame::endGame()
{
    sf::Thread thread(&MyGame::endThread, this);
    thread.launch();
}

void MyGame::endThread()
{

}
```

Alternatively you can use a static class method:

```
void MyGame::endGame()
{
    sf::Thread thread(&MyGame::endThread);
    thread.launch();
}

static void MyGame::endThread()
{

}
```

Please read the full documentation on SFML threads. Creating a local variable of a thread is not helpful. It will be destroyed when going out of scope and you want the thread to run, not to be deleted.

I see you are using the old SFML 1.6. Please read the [tutorial](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/system-threads.php) carefully. With the old version, you can only use the second option from the two above. You may want to switch to 2.0 or 2.1 as soon as you can.